# Question about meaning of "response" in this context

Tags: word-meaning

> To the Bahá’ís of Iran
>
> Papua New Guinea comprises a group of islands in the vast expanse of the waters of the Pacific, far, far away from the Cradle of the Faith.  We recently learned that **your sacrifices have so inspired the believers in that vibrant Bahá’í community in their highly energetic response to the exigencies of the Five Year Plan** that a group of them are working to make a television programme to bring to the attention of their compatriots the suffering that their deeply cherished fellow believers in Iran endure because of their adherence to the Cause.  In so many ways that extraordinary region, Australasia—where, before long, four Mash riqu’l-Adh kárs will shine out as beacons of the light of divine guidance and as testaments to the magnificent response of its population to Bahá’u’lláh’s call for unity and peace—is the embodiment of this emphatic promise by the Abhá Beauty regarding His Cause:  “Should they attempt to conceal its light on the continent, it will assuredly rear its head in the midmost heart of the ocean, and, raising its voice, proclaim:  ‘I am the life-giver of the world!’”

1. What does this part mean? **Response to the exigencies** . I know what **exigencies** mean. It has to do with development and accomplishment. I have a great deal of difficulty understanding what **response** here in this context really mean?
2. Could you also simplify the highlighted part in simple English, if possible.

Answer (score 2):

*Exigencies* are the demands or requirements specific to a particular situation. Responding to them means to adopt strategies to address them.

> your sacrifices have so inspired the believers in that vibrant Bahá’í
>   community in their highly energetic response to the exigencies of the
>   Five Year Plan

Your sacrifices have inspired the believers in that community as they endeavor to respond to the specific demands of the Five Year Plan.